# need to find all SPAN tags with this text and change CSS

Tags: jquery, css, each

I have a report where I want to find all the span tags that contain the text "GRAND TOTAL", and there is more than one, and change their css attribute background-color to red.

Here's what I have tried:

```
$('span').each(function(){ 
   if($(this).text() == "GRAND TOTAL"){ 
      $(this ).css( "background-color","red" ); 
   } 
});
```

And derivatives of the above. It is not clear to me how to format the above javascript code.

Comment: Post the HTML you want to apply this against please.

Comment: Code looks fine. What's your problem?

Comment: Maybe the code is executing before the dom is ready?

Comment: it changes nothing on the page, no css style changes.

Comment: In that case something else is wrong, the piece of code you shared is *fine*

Comment: Is your code wrapped in a document ready call? Can you recreate this in a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: Ok, maybe lets start from the beginning: do you include Jquery? Do you run your script after declaration of JQuery? What can you see in the console?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you have provided. the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : on this line:  $( this ).css( "background-color":"red" );

Comment: jquery is called after jquery CDN call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be so much easier:

```
$( "span:contains('GRAND TOTAL')" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Check: [**working JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wgLsK/) and for more info [**the Jquery website**](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

[**EDIT bases on comment**]

Try changing it to:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $( "span:contains('GRAND TOTAL')" ).css( "color", "red" );
});
```

Comment: Here's the code after changing it. No css change verified using inspector

Comment: you're right, I copied the entire page code to jsfiddle and it worked. BUT it still does not work on my page in the same browser.

Comment: @WebDev34 - Answer the questions in the comments above. Are you wrapping your jQuery in a document ready call as jsFiddle does by default?

Comment: changed it to the new code, nope. checked it in another browser, nope. frustrated but this is how learning happens. changed script to different places on page - no difference.

Comment: do you have an online example??

Comment: FIXED - ANSWERED. Moved script to around and finally found a place it worked! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         jQuery(function(){ $('span').each(function(){
              var temptext = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
              if(temptext  == "grand total"){
                $( this ).css( {"background-color":"red" });
              }
          });
         });
</script>
```

Try convert `.text()` to lowercase and use correct `.css()`

```
.css({ "background-color":"red" });
```

I have changed my post. `Use jQuery(function(){})` for init your function. It works for me

Comment: `.css()` portion is wrong, if you want to use `:` then do like this `.css({"":""})`

Comment: tried .css({ "background-color":"red" }); but it didn't change anything, still did not work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code works absolutly fine, but if it was me id use:

```
$( "span:contains('GRAND TOTAL')" ).css("background-color","red");
```

Comment: Damn, you are 18 sec faster :)

Comment: You definatly have issues elsewhere my friend.

Comment: @LinkinTED quickest gun slinger in the West

Comment: Alex - how do I track those down? Chrome console issues no alert

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : on this line:  $( this ).css( "background-color":"red" );